# SQL-SERVER: Properly using ISNULL to return default value

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple queries tied together that are generating ranked list then selecting the top from each. My problem is that the T4.area in my final SELECT is nullable and may have return null so I was trying to set a default value of 'TBD'.

If I break out the query by itself and run the below, it runs fine:

`SELECT ISNULL(MAX(area),'TBD') AS MDC
 FROM MDCcte3
WHERE row = 5`

But including it in my main query like the following returns no results:

`SELECT T1.area as Growth, T2.area AS Efficiency, T3.area as Risk, ISNULL(T4.area,'TBD') as MDC 
FROM Gcte3 T1, Ecte3 T2, Rcte3 T3, MDCcte3 T4
WHERE T1.row = 1 AND T2.row = 1 AND T3.row = 1 AND T4.row = 5
GROUP BY T1.area, T2.area, T3.area, T4.area`

---

```
    declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital1';

--GROWTH AREA RANK
WITH Gcte AS (
SELECT 4 score, growth1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 score, growth2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, growth3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, growth4 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, growth5 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
),

Gcte2 AS (
SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM Gcte
GROUP BY area
HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                   
),

Gcte3 AS (
SELECT area, score, 
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
FROM Gcte2
),                                 

--EFFICIENCY AREA RANK
Ecte AS (
SELECT 4 score, Efficiency1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 score, Efficiency2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, Efficiency3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, Efficiency4 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, Efficiency5 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
),

Ecte2 AS (
SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM Ecte
GROUP BY area
HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                  
),

Ecte3 AS (
SELECT area, score, 
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
FROM Ecte2
),

--RISK AREA RANK
Rcte AS (
SELECT 4 score, Risk1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 score, Risk2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, Risk3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, Risk4 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, Risk5 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
),

Rcte2 AS (
SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM Rcte
GROUP BY area
HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                  
),

Rcte3 AS (
SELECT area, score, 
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
FROM Rcte2
),

--ALL MDC'S FOR GER RANK
MDCcte AS (
SELECT 2 score, GrowthMDC1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL                                 
SELECT 1 score, GrowthMDC2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, GrowthMDC3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, EfficiencyMDC1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, EfficiencyMDC2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, EfficiencyMDC3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, RiskMDC1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, RiskMDC2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, RiskMDC3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital                                   
),

MDCcte2 AS (
SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM  MDCcte
GROUP BY area
HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                 
),

MDCcte3 AS (
SELECT area, score,
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) as row, 
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
FROM  MDCcte2
)




 SELECT T1.area as Growth, T2.area AS Efficiency, T3.area as Risk, ISNULL(T4.area,'TBD') as MDC 
FROM Gcte3 T1, Ecte3 T2, Rcte3 T3, MDCcte3 T4
WHERE T1.row = 1 AND T2.row = 1 AND T3.row = 1 AND T4.row = 4
GROUP BY T1.area, T2.area, T3.area, T4.area
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by likely needs the TBD as well.

```
SELECT T1.area as Growth, T2.area AS Efficiency, T3.area as Risk, ISNULL(T4.area,'TBD') as MDC 
FROM Gcte3 T1, Ecte3 T2, Rcte3 T3, MDCcte3 T4
WHERE T1.row = 1 AND T2.row = 1 AND T3.row = 1 AND (T4.row = 5 or t4.row is null)
GROUP BY T1.area, T2.area, T3.area, ISNULL(T4.area,'TBD')
```

I don't really like the way your handling the joins as it results in poor performance as the DB has to generate the Cartesian before the filter, but if you don't have performance issues.  *shrug* and it wasn't part of the question.

I really think you should join this...  Do the tables relate to eachother?

```
SELECT T1.area as Growth, T2.area AS Efficiency, T3.area as Risk, ISNULL(T4.area,'TBD') as MDC 
FROM Gcte3 T1, 
LEFT JOIN Ecte3 T2
 on T1.Row = T2.Row 
LEFT JOIN Rcte3 T3
 on T2.Trow = T3.Row
LEFT JOIN MDCcte3 T4
 on T3.Row = T4.Row and T4.Row = 5
WHERE T1.row = 1
GROUP BY T1.area, T2.area, T3.area, ISNULL(T4.area,'TBD')
```

This may work but I really would need to see sample data in T1, T2, T3 and T4 to better understand the dilemma and the expected results you're after.

As far as why it it works in your single query but not in the group.
The single query is returning the max value and if one isn't found then returning TBD for row 5 it doesn't have to contend with Joins.

When you're joinging the records each record is first combined with the records of the other table.

So if T1 has 10 records, T2 has 10 records, T3 has 10 Records and T4 has 5...
10*10*10*5 rows are generated 5000 then the database engine filters out the ones where T1.row <> 1 T2.row <> 2 and T3.row <> 1.
Then you say to filter out those where T4.Row <> 5.  There is no row five. so no records are returned.

This is why I think a left joins would work better as it will return all records from the preceding table and only those that match and then your NULLS get processed as TBD for T4.Area.

But for this to work the tables have to relate on something; and nothing stated so far indicates how they relate.

Comment: Hmm, still returning no results instead

Comment: There are records in T1-3.row=1. There are records for t4.row1-4. For Hospital1 there are no records in t4.row 5 or greater but I still need to show that theres nothing there. If i change to t4.row=4 then all results return as normal.

Comment: How? I don't understand that my stand alone query works as should but doesn't when attached? I'm not sure how else to do it. Seems like this should work.

Comment: `WHERE T1.row = 1 AND T2.row = 1 AND T3.row = 1 AND (T4.row = 5 or t4.row is null)` to accommodate the NULL potential for t4 in the where clause  I'll add a entirely different query joining things togeter ASSUMINg the ROW is the unique value for each table on which we can join.  (using left joins)

Comment: To answer your question. Everything is from the same table `Survey` but adding `(T4.row = 5 or t4.row is null)` still shows notta :/

Comment: Create a fiddle and I might be able to help some more.  you seem to be going though a lot of steps to get your results; which Im' not sure is needed.

Comment: I'm just gonna accept your answer but go a different route by just keeping the 2 separate and going from there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No need to accept, you could withdraw the question I promise not to take any offense! or keep it out there if you want to look at something different.  Here to try and help!